# Tag synonym request: [encryption] → [cryptography]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The [encryption](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption) tag got created sometime in the last year.  The [cryptography](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) tag completely covers the same topic, and it makes little sense to distinguish the two skills, especially when it comes to earning credit towards tag badges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed. Done.